# I can retrieve but not usefully use data from a firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app that stores and retrieves data about patients in a hospital using a firebase database. What I want is to be able to press a button, call a function to retrieve the data and create a new patient object for each record, return the list of patient objects, and finally pass the list as an argument to the next screen so I can show the list.

Currently, the function retrieves the data using `databaseRef.once().then()` but it seems to work asynchronously, meaning the function returns and empty list before the list can be filled with data so I'm just passing an empty list to the next screen. There is a definite gap in my understading of asynchronous functions so any solutions or explanations would be appreceiated.

Below is the function for retrieving data as it is now, and also how the function is being called.

```
List getDatabase(var databaseRef, var snap) {
  Patient patient = Patient();
  List <Patient> patientList = [];

  databaseRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap)  {

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> entries = snap.value;  //creates a map of everything in database

    for (var k in entries.keys) {     //for each key, patient details are recorded and 
                                      //the instance is appended to the list
      patient.patientID = k;
      patient.firstName = entries[k]["First Name"];
      patient.sex = entries[k]["Sex"];

      patientList.add(patient);
      print(patientList)   //a few seconds after the empty list is returned, this prints
                           //out all the data I would like to return from the fuinction
      patient.clear();
    }
  }
  );
  print(patientList);        //This current prints an empty list as the databaseRef.once().then()
                             //is asynchronus and takes a second to run in the background
  return patientList;
```

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Open Form'),
  onPressed: () {
    List patientList = getDatabase(databaseRef, snapshot);
    print(patientList)   //prints out empty list
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'viewEntries', arguments: patientList);                 
  }
),
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to return data *now* that is loaded asynchronously. When your `return patientList` runs, the `patientList.add(patient)` has not run yet - and there's nothing you can do to change that.

What you can do is return a so-called `Future`, which is the promise to return something in the... future. Also see the Dart documentation on [async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

In your scenario that means that the `getDatabase` function looks like this:

```
Future<List> getDatabase(var databaseRef) async {
  Patient patient = Patient();
  List <Patient> patientList = [];

  var snap = await databaseRef.once()

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> entries = snap.value;  //creates a map of everything in database

  for (var k in entries.keys) {     //for each key, patient details are recorded and 
                                      //the instance is appended to the list
    patient.patientID = k;
    patient.firstName = entries[k]["First Name"];
    patient.sex = entries[k]["Sex"];

    patientList.add(patient);

    patient.clear();
  }
  return patientList;
}
```

You'll see that the code is almost the same, but the use of `async` in the declaration and `await` in the body now means that this returns a `Future<List>`: so it immediately returns the promise of something that contains the data in the future.

---

To call this function you can now either use `await` or `then`:

With `then`:

```
var future = getDatabase(ref);
future.then((patientList) {
  print(patientList);
})
```

And with `await`:

```
var patientList = await getDatabase(ref);
print(patientList);
```

If you use the latter syntax, you will have to mark the function that contains this code as `async` too. It's marking a function as `async` that allows you to use `await` in it.

---

If you want to render this code in the widget tree, use a `FutureBuilder`. This widget knows how to deal with the asynchronous nature of a `Future`.

Comment: I think you might have missed the async keyword in the declaration. Either way, when I put it in the declaration and try to use var patientList = await getDatabase(ref), I get an error saying await can only be used in async methods.

Comment: I indeed missed `async`. Good catch. I added it now.

Comment: and it looks like I missed an async in the onPressed.

Comment: If you're using `await getDatabase(ref)` in the call site, any function *that* code is in will need to be marked as `async` too indeed. It's marking a method as `async` that allows you to use `await` in there. If you use the `then()` syntax, you shouldn't have to mark the method with the `getDatabase(ref).then(...)` code as `async` though.

Comment: Hey @Finno. Did you get this working now?

Comment: I couldn't get it working a few days ago. I've decided to put it at the back of my mind and go back to it tomorrow. If I still can't get it working I'll send the error!

Comment: Yes I have managed to do it using await, and a while loop after to stop the code from moving on until a the getDatabase function returns a value. Thanks for the help!